# How to make excel auto calculate contents of a single cell

Tags: autocomplete

So, here is my problem. I have a cell "a1" containing this exact text "3+5". I want a formula that will make excel auto calculate in cell "a2" the sum of the contents, respectively "8". Can this be done ? Thanks

Comment: This has some interesting answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Comment: @Vylix Not helpful

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your requirement? The linked question already implies that there is no such function/formula, and the closest possible I can imagine is http://stackoverflow.com/a/4472470/3873736

Comment: You are probably right. What if we can solve this another way. I was thinking about extracting the numbers in separate cells to solve this. First I will use this formula to extract the left side of the "+" sign "LEFT(A1;IF(ISERROR(FIND("+";A1;1));LEN(A1);FIND("+";A1;1)-1))" and then I use "RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("+";A1))" to extract the right side of the "+" sign. And it works well, until I get to the numbers with decimals and the right function doesn't work the way it suppose to or maybe I'm using it wrong (Example: 2+3.5). Maybe someone can help me solve the problem using this method.

Comment: @Kim, Excel doesn't work the way you want it to.  The linked SO question covers all the practical ways people have come up with to accomplish it.  What you describe in your comment is basically to build a formula interpreter using Excel functions, which gets very unwieldy and impractical if it needs to handle a general case of any formula.  The site tries to focus on real-world problems and practical solutions.  People may not be interested in investing their time to develop a poor solution of potential use to one person just because the approach is possible.

Comment: So your answer is, we should have no solution than a poor solution as you call it because it's not practical. It makes sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kim, no.  What I said is that we already have practical solutions, so people aren't likely to want to spend their time developing a mini-application that is not as good as the existing solutions.  You've given no indication of your usecase for which the existing solutions don't work.